# Error adding MS SQL Server connection in Sharpdevelop Entity Framework wizard

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sharpdevelop

Trying to add a new connection for MS SQL Server in Sharpdevelop via the Entity Framework Wizard, and I get the following not very helpful error:

[image: Sharpdevelop Add new connection error]

Does anyone have any clues as to exactly what it is that is not supported? The version number on its own is not very helpful.

I'm using Sharpdevelop 4.4.0.9722.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that SQL Server 2000 SP3a (version 8) is not supported, which is true for EF5 and newer. http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.dk/